# Reload/Re-Find Jquery Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

To demonstrate my issue, here I have small demo Script:

**/user.html** =

```
<div id="user-box"></div>
```

**js =**

```
class UserComponent {
  constructor({}) {
    this.srcFile = "/user.html";
    this.parentBox = $("#container-box");

    this.childBox = $("#user-box");
  };

  show(){
        this.parentBox.load(this.srcFile, function() {
            this.childBox.html("<p>Hello</p>")
        }.bind(this));
  };
}
```

The problem is that this line does not work correctly:

```
 this.childBox.html("<p>Hello</p>")
```

For me the problem seems to be that when `this.chilBox` is referenced in the constructor, it does not yet exist in the DOM.

When I rewrite my code to:

```
        this.parentBox.load(this.srcFile, function() {
            var childBox = $("#user-box");
            childBox.html("<p>Hello</p>")
        }.bind(this));
```

Then it works. But I would like to reference the element in the constructor.

**How can I reference the element in the constructor and then use it later when it exists?**

I tried `this.childBox.find().html("<p>Hello</p>")` but like this it did not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could initialize your UserComponent class within a $(document).ready, so that DOM is complete when creating the new UserComponent() - or in general fill the UserComponent.childBox when the DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

try this

`this.childBox.html($("<p>Hello</p>"))`

instead of

`this.childBox.html("<p>Hello</p>")`